# EF, C#: Select into field when retrieving Model

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

So I have a simple query where I select AppDictionary objects from my db.
My AppDictionary object has a field for 3 languages (EN,FR,ES) and a field called "Text".  My goal is that based on whatever language the application is set to, that value is what is in the Text field.  For instance, I could have something like this.

EN   |  FR       |  ES

Shoe | chaussure | Zapato

Should the user have their language set to English, the Text field will be populated with Shoe, if it's Spanish, the Text field would be populated with Zapato.

I was wondering if there was anyway for me to do an EF read from the db i.e context.Appdictionaries.Where... And have it populate the Text field based on a parameter I give it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

In raw SQL, I would just alias it, but I'm not sure how to tell EF to do that.

Sorry, here is what my class looks like.  Note the fields for all languages.

```
public class AppDictionary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Text;
    ...
    public string EN { get; set; }

    public string FR { get; set; }

    public string DE { get; set; }

    public string PT { get; set; }

    public string ES { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is the structure of your AppDictionary table? It's unclear whether you have a row that represents each key + language, or if you have all the languages in a single row with a key.

Comment: hmm.. you have 1000+ rep points, yet you provide a question with no code snippet.. note: you do describe the type...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Where<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate)` on your `IQueryable<T>` types, or rather your `Context` will return `IQueryable<T>`, where `T` is your `object` - `AppDictionary` (presumably).

The resulting SQL will create a `WHERE` clause that uses the predicate;

When executed (or Enumerated on), the query will be populated with the results.

```
//presumed to be your 'Entity'.
public partial class AppDictionary
{
    public string Language {get;set;}
    public string Text {get;set;}
}


public IEnumerable<string> GetResults(string lang)
{
    var query = context.AppDictionaries.Where((record) => String.Compare(record.Language.ToLower(), lang.ToLower(), true) == 0);

    return query.AsEnumerable(); //executes and loads at this point
}
```

It's a fairly straight forward query expression.

Comment: note that I'm using case-insensitive conditional check: i.e. 'ToLower()` and I'm only concerned with whether the language meets the criteria of having the string **starting** at the first character position..

Comment: thus, if you pass `E` you will return `EN` and `ES` records... so take that into consideration..